# Pass a value greater than maximum value of long type to fseek in C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I need to pass some values to the `fseek()` method in C which are greater than the maximum value of the signed long type (2147483647). But if I do like below the value of the result is -1 which is not success. Is there anyway that I can do this?

```
//fp is the pointer to fopen method
unsigned long long index=2147483648;
int status = fseek(fp, index, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: wow... what kind of crazy massive file is this that requires a seek to somewhere much longer than the maximum value of unsigned long?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann 2GB files is nothing. I've dealt with (single) files as large `6 TB`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: We are in 2012, how 2GB file is a 'crazy massive file'?

Comment: Heh.  Yeah, I guess I have it lucky that I don't have to deal with psd files or sql db's on a regular basis.

Comment: I think a 2 GB file is massive for plenty of people. (But of course, not really all that uncommon…)

Comment: (Also, I totally read "2 TB" the first time.)

Comment: @Wevah Considering that a single game can be a ~8gb download today (skyrim from steam was larger and I think the witcher2 was >10 or so) I think many people will have contact with such large files indirectly ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you tagged this with "Objective-C", I'm assuming you are also thinking about Macintosh.

[Check out `fseeko`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fseeko.3.html) (which takes a 64bit number).

Comment: +1. The benefit of this is that the width of `off_t` is baked into 32- or 64-bit compilation.

Comment: (Baked in with the use of the `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` compilation option.)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the 64-bit version of `fseek()`:

- Windows: [`_fseeki64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx)
- Linux: [`fseeko()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseeko) with `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` or `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

And for `lseek()`:

- Windows: [`_lseeki64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yee101t.aspx)
- Linux: [`lseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) with `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` or `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

There's also [`lseek64()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek64), but as mentioned by @R.. (see comments), it should not be used.

Comment: `lseek64` is the 64-bit version of `lseek`, not `fseek`, but perhaps more importantly it should never be used. Instead compile **everything** with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` (this should not even be an option; it should be default and you should put it in all your project makefiles) and use the standard function `fseeko`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, gimme a min. to make that correct. I'll mention both `lseek` and `fseek`.

Comment: @R. Changes made. Let me know if there's anything else I should fix.

Comment: `lseek64` is also wrong. Should just be `lseek` with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.